# Trouble with display on IMac

Tags: 18.04, display, mac

I upgraded to the latest Ubuntu (18.04) on my repurposed Imac and I have been having several issues that I have not been able to find answers for as of yet. My screen at times shifts the color palette (similar to https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2397417). This can be reverted by locking the screen, letting it turn off and logging back in. 
As of late my terminal and other menu bars have been turning into black and white squares at times which I only seem to be able to fix with a restart.
My question is whether there is a certain graphics driver I can update that could fix all this, as it used to work just fine on the previous Ubuntu distro (I think I had 17.10 but I am not quite sure)?